# What does "?=" do in regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

Can anyone tell me what "?=" does when using regex? 
Here is an example of the code fragment I am trying to decipher:

```
password.matches("(?=.*\\d.*\\d.*)^[\\w]{8}.*$");
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=question+mark+equals+regex ... and click the [first hit](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [**positive lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). In that particular expression, it is saying that your password must have at least two digits (`\d`).

Also note that a lookahead doesn't *consume* input, it is merely an **assertion**.

For example, in your regex, the lookahead part (`(?=.*\\d.*\\d.*)`) asserts that your `password` contains at least two digits, and the rest of the expression consumes the entire string, and tries to match at least 8 word characters (i.e., `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`) at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 3):

It's a lookahead: A zero-width match that checks to see if the position is followed by the given expression.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

In your scenario, you are looking for a string that:

- begins with a string containing two digits (enforced by the lookahead)
- begins with 8 word characters (matched by the rest of the regex)

The lookahead is not actually part of the match. It behaves much like a word boundary (`\b`) or beginning of string (`^`).